# Setting the height and width of inner most html element

Tags: html

As shown in this example, the height and width of the innermost **div** tag is set to the height and width of the browser window. How can I set the height and width of the same element without setting the height and width of all it's parent elements through css or inline style attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width:100%;height:100%;">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div style="wiidth:100%;height:100%;">
      <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div style="border: 2px solid #000000;width:100%;height:100%;">Innermost Div</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Or use:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

See the working snippets:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="border: 2px solid #000000; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute;">Innermost Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What? I am not sure what you are meaning about "agreement"! @GRC.

Answer (score 2):

I think You can use:

## div_name {width:100wv; height:100wh;}

wv ==> wievport width

wh ==> wievport height

Comment: This is good example unfortunately I found this to work on some browsers and not on the others.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> % ==>  Defines the height in percent of the containing block

so with height=100% you cannot do it because 100% is related to parent block, but you can do it with px, em, wh and vw. What I will do is set body height to min-height, set most inner div min-height to the same height as well.

SIDE NOTE:
You do not need to do `height = 100%` and `width = 100%` on body element. they are already 100% as default.